# How to make a sum vanish?

Tags: soft-question, summation

This is a very very basic question but I just cannot think of a way to tackle it for some reason.

Say I have three numbers $a,b,c$ with the sum $a+b+c\neq1$. Now if I want to make this sum equal to 1 all I need to do is to make a small adjustment to these three numbers. So then $$a\rightarrow \frac{a}{a+b+c}$$
$$b\rightarrow \frac{b}{a+b+c}$$
$$c\rightarrow \frac{c}{a+b+c}$$.

Now my question is what do I do to make the sum $0$. I am sure the answer is as basic as this but my brain has gone blank. Hope someone could give me an answer thanks a lot.(Honestly I do not know what tags to use for this!)

Comment: What if $a+b+c=0$?

Comment: Pardon me, but I'm not entirely clear what you actually want to ask. Do you wish to find numbers $(a',b',c')$ which are proportional to $(a,b,c)$, such that their sum is $1$ or $0$ respectively? If so, the second case just does not work. If not, why exactly can you not say $a'=b'=c'=0$ and we're done? What are the conditions you work with?

Comment: @SomeMathStudent I just want to find proportional numbers that sum up to 0

Comment: @SomeMathStudent You can forget the part I told about the sum being equal to 1 in my question that was just an example I thought of

Comment: $a\rightarrow -(b+c)$ and $b\rightarrow b$ also $c\rightarrow c$

Comment: If $(a+b+c) \neq 0$ then for every number $d\neq0$ you have also that $d(a+b+c)\neq0$ so you will have a solution if you choose different weights or proportions. Is that ok, because it seems that you want to multiply all of them with the same weight?

Comment: Well, if you do want proportional numbers that add to $0$, you have a problem. Being proportional implies that there is a constant $d$ such that $(a,b,c)=d\cdot(a',b',c')$, which also means that $a'+b'+c'=d\cdot(a+b+c)=0$. If $a+b+c\neq 0$, that leads to $d=0$, which implies that $a'=b'=c'=0$, which is probably not the kind of result you are looking for?

Comment: @SomeMathStudent I guess not. Maybe a fair adjustment then to make it zero?

Comment: Trouble is, what adjustments do you call fair? If we just say "well, we have $a+b$, so let's just say $c=-(a+b)$", then sure, your result will be $0$. However, we are not proportional to our original numbers anymore. So unless we know what transformations *exactly* are allowed, it is kind of hard to give you any satisfactory result.

Comment: @SomeMathStudent Yes I agree being fair is a very vague expression.

Comment: @Stefanos I guess different weights will do

Comment: @SomeMathStudent Here is a small thought. What if the there is method that makes a minimum change to the numbers to get a zero sum ?I guess we can call that fair if such a method exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you talked about a minimal change to your vector $(a,b,c)$ before, I'd actually suggest not looking at $a-a'+b-b'+c-c'$ as, simply put, those terms might cancel each other out. To get a minimal change in a more geometrical sense, I'd rather use some norm as $|a-a'|+|b-b'|+|c-c'|$, minimizing which is fortunately equivalent to minimizing the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$, meaning the length of the vector $(a-a',b-b',c-c')$.

Now, if that is what we are trying to do, we actually have a fairly nice geometric interpretation of the problem. If you look at all your solutions, they are on the plane $x+y+z=0$.

Our point $(a,b,c)$, however, is not. What we want to do is connect this point to aforementioned plane, using the shortest possible path.

Since in euclidean geometry the shortest possible path from a plane to a point is always along a straight line perpendicular to our plane, this helps us a lot - because we *know* what lines are normal to our plane, since it's given in normal-vector form.

Thus we want to draw a line parallel to the normal vector $(1,1,1)$ through our point $(a,b,c)$ and find the intersection with the plane $x+y+z=0$. The result will be our point $(a',b',c')$, and the length of $(a-a',b-b',c-c')$ will be the shortest possible distance you travel in order for the sum of your components to be $0$.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Then if $a,b,c$ are numbers that do not add up to $0$ then 
$$a\overset{\cdot bc}\longrightarrow abc$$
$$b\overset{\cdot (-2ac)}\longrightarrow -2abc$$
$$c\overset{\cdot ab}\longrightarrow abc$$ always add up to zero. But that is only one choice from infinitely many (it is just cyclically symmetric, nothing more).

Comment: Thanks. true there can be many methods. Here is a small question. What if the transformed numbers are $(a',b'c')$. Is there a method to do this so that $(a-a',b-b',c-c')$ is minimum?

Comment: Ok, putting a constraint in the solution makes much more sense, but it is a more difficult question. I do not know if I can answer it immediately satisfactorily. I will have to think over it

Comment: Again, you should be more specific in what you want to minimize. Do you want to minimize the sum $a-a'+b-b'+c-c'$ or something alike?

Comment: Nope I meant the change done to each variable is minumum

Comment: a−a′+b−b′+c−c′ =a+b+c anyway

Comment: Ok, yes indeed.